# mix setStyleSheet and setFont: wrong background

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I merge several classes and functions into only two classes,
so it looks strange and ugly.
The problem that my class `MyW` at the end of constructor
set background to white, but it's child QLabel has background
from `Page`, not from `MyW`.

And question why?
I know that if I  remove magic with fonts in `MyW`,
or call setStyleSheet at the begining like this:
`setStyleSheet("border:none;background:#ffffff;color:#000000;");`
I get the right result (white background),
but I can not understand why font make influence to background,
and why there is difference between set stylesheet in two steps,
instead of one?

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>

class MyW : public QWidget {
public:
  MyW(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent) {
    setStyleSheet("border:none;");
    setFont(QFont{"Arial", 42});
    setStyleSheet(styleSheet() + "background:#ffffff;color:#000000;");
    auto lbl = new QLabel{"AAAA", this};

    lbl->ensurePolished();
  }
};

class Page : public QWidget {
public:
  Page(QWidget *parent) : QWidget{parent} {
    setStyleSheet("background:#f0f4f7;");
    auto item = new MyW{this};
  }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QApplication a(argc, argv);

  Page p{nullptr};
  p.resize(400, 800);
  p.show();
  return a.exec();
}
```

**Update**: I removed all not important parts, like layouts, QApplication::setFont and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am sure that reason is not in `auto font = QApplication::font();`, but
in `QWidget::setFont` call. You can check it, for example, by replacing font stuff with:

```cpp
QFont font;
font.setPixelSize(42);
setFont(font);
```

The "magic" behind this is cache that is used inside Qt to deal with style sheets.
You can find hint in  [qtbase/src/widgets/styles/qstylesheetstyle.cpp](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/styles/qstylesheetstyle.cpp.html), look at usage of
`static QStyleSheetStyleCaches *styleSheetCaches = 0;`

Qt does not use `QWidget::styleSheet` property directly,
it parses it and caches result.
There are several triggers for parsing(re-parsing) of `QWidget::styleSheet`:

1. Call of `QWidget::ensurePolished` (it is done automatically when your widget
   becomes visible for the first time);
2. Call of `setStyleSheet` but only in the case if your widget called `QWidget::ensurePolished` at least once;
3. Call of `QWidget::setFont` or `QWidget::setPalette` (only if your widget does not have an empty styleSheet).

In your case your problem is a combination of (1-2) and (3):
after force caching of the parsed stylesheet via `QWidget::setFont` your widget is still not "polished",
so the next call of `setStyleSheet` does not update the cached style sheet that was created on `setFont` step,
so on the step with `lbl->ensurePolished();` you actually have a style sheet with "border:none;" plus font, plus background of parent.

You can call `this->ensurePoslished()` before `lbl->ensurePoslished()` to fix this issue or as suggested by @William Miller use stylesheet to set font,
or place `setFont` after all calls of `setStyleSheet`

Answer (score 2):

Per the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#setFont) on `QApplication::setFont()`,

> **Warning**: Do not use this function in conjunction with Qt Style Sheets. The font of an application can be customized using the "font" style sheet property. To set a bold font for all QPushButtons, set the application styleSheet() as "QPushButton { font: bold }"

Since they explicitly warn against this I would expect there is an inheritance conflict when using style sheets in conjunction with the application level default font, so the line

```
QApplication::setFont(font);
```

and subsequently,

```
auto font = QApplication::font();
```

May not produce the expected behavior. Their alternative is set the application-level `styleSheet()` for your class, i.e.

```
setStyleSheet(" MyW { font-family: 'Garamond' }");
```

So it seems the short answer is that they don't support it.

The reason it makes a difference "between set stylesheet in two steps, instead of one" is not because you are setting the style sheet in two different steps but because you call `QApplication::font()` between the steps and as this is unsupported behavior, it is producing the unexpected result.

Comment: If look at source code you can see, that `QApplication::font` is not the reason of problem (you can replace it with default font creation), but the real reason is `setFont` and `setStyleSheet` cooperation. So the diagnosis is wrong, but the treatment is right.

Comment: I have to question that given that the docs explicitly warn against using `QApplication::setFont` with `setStylSheet` and given that you are seeing unexpected behavior. Have you tried doing it without `QApplication::setFont` or no?

Comment: No, I haven't even read documentation. I just read source code of Qt. And I am sure, if you remove all metions of `QApplicatioin::setFont` and `QApplication::font` and just leave `QFont font;font.setPixelSize(42);setFont(font);` between `setStyleSheet` calls then you got the same problem as before.

Comment: I see, I am curious then why they issue a warning if the source does not merit it... perhaps the documentation is out of date.

Comment: No, the documentation is right. But context is important.  `QWidget::setFont` merge font with style sheet, while `QApplication::setFont` just set global variable (and send event to all widgets), so all not desired effects are possible. But it is completely safe to call it just before any widget will be created, just like in code above.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but @fghj 's answer is more close to true, I removed all not related parts, including `QAppliction::setFont` and `QApplication::font` but issue/bug was not fixed by this. Yes, usage of `QWidget::setStyleSheet` instead of `QWidet::setFont` works, but it is not related to `QApplication::*font*`